# Swift4 right way to test substrings against strings?

Tags: swift, string

I'm parsing the first two characters on a line of text and doing lots of comparisons against possible patterns:

In my Card class:

```
static let ourTypes = ["PL", "SY", "XT"]
```

In lots of other places:

```
if Card.ourTypes.contains(line[0..<2]) { continue }
```

Swift4 (3?) changed the []'s to return a Substring. I know I can cast it back with `String(line[0..<2])`, but I suspect that's the wrong solution... is there a better way?

Comment: What is `line`? You cannot subscript String with Ints. Or you have some extension?

Comment: I am using an extension. The fact that the extension threads are so popular indicates a problem in my eyes.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by _the extension threads are so popular_, but if you can accept such a possibly inefficient extension, using `String(line[0..<2])` would be a practical solution.

Comment: OO, search here on the topic and look at the votes.

Comment: Please show some example, and even if it got 1000+ upvotes, I would not use such extension in my apps.

Comment: Feel free to do what you wish.

Comment: I'm just curious why you want to avoid something like `String(line[0..<2])` despite the fact you use such extension. If you care about efficiency avoid both. If you do not care about efficiency accept both.

Comment: I am further confused. How do I avoid the String(anyAPIyouwish)?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _anyAPIyouwish_. If it actually means any output from arbitrary APIs, there's no generally-efficient way. If you focus on `String`-`Substring` issue, I can show you some alternatives.

Comment: Feel free to show the alternatives of which you speak.

Comment: I would not push them on to you if you not need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194991/discussion-between-maury-markowitz-and-ooper).

Comment: Sorry, but _chat_ is the worst feature in SO in my opinion, so it's time to leave here for me now. You should better clarify what you think is better under what condition. Both answers matt's and vacawama's can be the better way in many practical cases.

Comment: @OOPer I’m curious to hear what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String cast, while a bit jarring, is not expensive. Deriving a true independent substring from a string simply *is* a two-step process: access the slice, then unlink the indices and storage from the original. That is all that `String()` means here. So I think your original approach is actually correct and nonproblematic.

If you really want to stay in the String world, though, you can, by calling `removeSubrange` instead of taking a slice. You give up the convenience of slice notation and slice-related methods, but everything depends on your priorities. And by the way, if `contains` is your main test here, use a Set, not an Array:

```
let ourTypes = Set(["PL", "SY", "XT"])
var line = "PLARF"
line.removeSubrange(line.index(line.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)...)
ourTypes.contains(line) // true
```

Comment: I am accepting this as the solution because it appears there *is* no solution. The current system in Swift makes the syntax of my code, or anyone processing a text file, absolutely abysmal.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to make your `ourTypes` array to be `[Substring]`, then you wouldn't have to convert your `Substring` to make `contains` work:

```
static let ourTypes: [Substring] = ["PL", "SY", "XT"]

if Card.ourTypes.contains(line.prefix(2)) { continue }
```

@matt's observation that searching with `contains` is better with a `Set` (because it's more efficient) can be accomplished with:

```
static let ourTypes: Set<Substring> = ["PL", "SY", "XT"]
```

Comment: I think this will work, but am I the only one that thinks this is an absolute shitshow? Now I can't use the items as strings.

Comment: Swift is strongly typed.  What can you do?

Comment: Well @MauryMarkowitz hence my comment that casting to String is not expensive. It is not really a _type_ cast; all it does is unlink the indices / storage.

Comment: Yeah, but it totally pollutes the source with spurious text that ultimately has zero effect. In my case I have to do trims, so I have to "cast" it *everywhere*.

Comment: But you can readily write an extension to clean up the code if you object to the look of the thing.

Comment: @vacawama Even though we both had this idea, I'm going to suggest it's not a good one, as long-lived substrings are usually a bad smell.

Comment: Also if the test is really going to be `contains` you should use a Set, not an array.

Comment: See my revised answer, which shows how to derive a prefix while staying in the String world. I don't think it's worth the effort, but it can be done.

Comment: @matt, I think long lived substrings are generally a bad idea because those substrings keep the original strings "hostage".  Here, we're merely enforcing a type that makes the searching "prettier".

Comment: I could be wrong but I am worried that we are teaching a bad practice. I'm thinking that String coercion _is_ the best practice and that the OP's impulse that this is somehow wrong or ugly is just mistaken. Accordingly I've removed the Substring array from my own answer.